# NSTextField commitEditing to a binding

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nstextfield

How does `textShouldEndEditing` for an `NSTextField` usually update coca bindings (by default)? I've overridden the method and, as a side-effect, bindings are no longer updating so I want to reinstate this behavior. The only advice I've seen is to create an additional `NSObjectController` and `commitEditing` to that but what code did the original `textShouldEndEditing` use?

In my situation, my `NSTextField` has its value bound to an `NSController` called *Jobs*. From my `NSTextField` subclass, I can see no way to reference *Jobs* to `commitEditing`. *Jobs* is present in Interface Builder as a result of creating an `NSArrayController` for a *Jobs* entity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were two answers for this that I could find:

1. `infoForBinding`. I wasn't aware of this method and it can be used to identify the binding controller and target it.
2. I had thought an `IBOutlet` couldn't be used with subClasses I wasn't initialising in IB but I forgot I could access the outlet from the dropped in subClassed `NSTextFields` in my application. It was then easy to create an `IBOutlet` to my `NSArrayController` and all worked as I hoped.